# File Exist For Python 3.7.1

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-3.7

in my project I'm doing, I've always used this part of the script to check if a file existed or not:

```
path = os.path.join("myfile.txt")
conf = Path(path)
try:
    lc = conf.resolve()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("new")
else:
    print("load")
```

It always worked (I used Python 3.4). Now, for some reason, I wanted to change the interpreter and use Python 3.7.1

Now, I only get printed "load", regardless of whether the file exists or not.
How should I solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior of [`Path.resolve()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) changed in Python 3.6; you now need to pass `strict=True` to make it fail when the file doesn't exist.

But it's probably easier to use [`Path.exists()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.exists) instead. (Or [`os.path.exists()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) if you want to work with path strings rather than `Path` objects.)

Comment: +1, using an failure / exception for a regular feature is  (checking if a file exists) is always a bad idea.

Comment: More than anything else, I needed a safe way to determine if a file existed or not. This is because I used it mainly to load or create a configuration file at the beginning of the script. I had found this method, so I did not know about this change in Python 3.6

Comment: The file verification was normally found in `__init__` in a class that took care of the configuration file.

Comment: @BlackFenix06 why not just try always opening the file for reading and create it if you get a `FileNotFoundError` exception during that?

Comment: @ZainanVictorZhou Well, Python is less particular about that than other languages (in particular contrast to C++ where throwing an exception entails significant overhead). But I do agree that ways of doing things that don't involve throwing an exception are usually preferable.

Comment: @David Z Sorry for the delay in the answer. The two options you suggested are good for both Windows, Mac and Linux? Or are there incompatibility problems?

Comment: @BlackFenix06 What sort of incompatibility problems do you have in mind? Any particular reason you bring up that possibility?

Comment: @David Z I ask because I know that some instructions or functions maybe work only on one platform, or they are incompatible on another. Since I only have Windows, I can not test the script on Linux and Mac. Wanting to make the script as compatible as possible, I have to rely on the information given. That's why the question.

Comment: @BlackFenix06 Ah, well I was a little surprised you asked because it would be very strange for commonly used functions like these to have significant platform differences not listed in the documentation. I can only personally attest that `os.path.exists()` works on Linux, but I believe all the functions I mentioned should work on all platforms.

Comment: Thanks for your help